# In an ideal OO design, should inherited objects implicity call super() on each of his methods?

Tags: oop, inheritance, methods, superclass

That is, when child.update() is called, should the instance of a derived class implicity call all his superclasses's update() on itself before?

Comment: If it's truly OOP then the superclasses method's are important and should be run in case they modify variables or call other functions/methods. Unless you are overtly _overriding_ the method, then no, you want yours to _replace_ it.

Comment: It depends: does the child class require the functionality of the parent? If yes, then yes. If no, then of course not! Child classes are free to completely redefine the functionality of the parent.

Comment: dlev: So should it implicity call the parent's functionality and provide a way to block that behavior, or not call anything and provide a way to do it?

Comment: TheZ: I'll edit the question with an additional question over this.

Comment: @Dokkat Like I said, it really depends on what you *want* the code to do. Do you want the parent functionality? If so, do you want it to occur before or after your own code? Should it always be executed? Answer those questions, and then your original question answers itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no good answer (in the languages I know).  Sometimes you want to replace the super method.  Sometimes you want to slip something in *before* it executes, and sometimes *after*.  It does seem the extending class needs to know more about the details of the class it's overriding than it should have to.  (This gets awkward with closed-source systems.)  Also, the base class really wants to control the behaviour of the calling class sometimes, to force the super method to be called, which isn't right either.  I think the best thing is for the super class to *document* its overridable methods as best it can so the overriding programmer can guess what to do.

The closest I've come to handing this properly and rightly is to make the target method so it cannot be overridden, then have it call a method or methods that do nothing but that *can* be overridden.  Then the overriding class can override whichever methods interest it without being able to undermine the superclass.

The ultimate programming language will have a fool-proof solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what the superclass / base-class function does. Sometimes I call it first, sometimes I call it last. Sometimes I call it conditionally, and once in a while, I don't call it at all.

Many times (this is coming from a C# background), the base class function just raises an event, and the child class overrides that method to get the event-like functionality. There are cases where the child doesn't want that event to be raised:

```
class Base {
   public event EventHandler UnhandledError;
   protected virtual void OnUnhandledError(Error error) {
       if (UnhandledError != null)
          UnhandledError(this, EventArgs.Empty);
   }
}

class Derived : Base {
    protected override void OnUnhandledError(Error error) {
       if (HandleError(error))
          return;                 // We took care of it. Don't raise the event.

       // We couldn't handle it. Let the base class raise the event.
       base.OnUnhandledError(error);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Someone might need to override update() and wants to prevent exactly any call from a parent. In that case in implicit call would not only hurt performance it also might do things you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

You are not **wrapping** a class into another, you are **inheriting** from a super-class.

Overriding super-class methods you should call `super.method()` only when you need to extend behavior of parent `method()`.